# Cross platform version of __PTRDIFF_TYPE__

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, c-preprocessor, ptrdiff-t

Is there a cross-platform way to determine whether `ptrdiff_t` is the same as `long` or `long long` during preprocessing?

I know `__PTRDIFF_TYPE__` should give the type with gcc/g++, but it doesn't seem to be defined in VC/VC++ for Windows.  Is there a better approach than the following?

```
#ifndef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__
# if _WIN64
#  define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long long
# else
#  define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long
# endif
#endif
```

If not possible during preprocessing, is there a compile time approach?  I'm looking for a non-C++11 solution, but if you've got a really nice modern solution, feel free to share!

Comment: Why do you need to know? The point of defining `ptrdiff_t` in the standard library is that you don't have to care how it's defined.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a Python2 `PyIntObject` to a `ptrdiff_t`, and there are different methods to convert it to `long` and to `long long`.  I suppose technically the long long approach would always work, but it's not as clean since Python internally stores the value in a long.

Comment: Please add that information to the question. You have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167210). You need to convert a `PyIntObject` to a `ptrdiff_t` but rather than asking about that, you're asking how to determine which type is used for `ptrdiff_t`. (BTW, `ptrdiff_t` isn't necessarily either `long` or `long long`, but it's likely to be one or the other on any platform that supports Python.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compile-time approach is very obvious:

```
if (sizeof(ptrdiff_t) == sizeof(long))
```

or

```
if (sizeof(ptrdiff_t) == sizeof(long long))
```

TMK, there are no portable defines for this. However, this is just a minor obstacle. With just a little bit of scripting, any compile-time test of this nature can be trivially converted to, essentially, a preprocessor-based test, using standard tools like [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) and [automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/). These are standard tools used by thousands of free software libraries and tools, for this precise purpose.

Comment: On some implementations, `long` and `long long` are the same size (but they're still distinct types).

Comment: This would merit another sizeof(long) == sizeof(long long) test, that's all.

Comment: If `sizeof(long) == sizeof(long long)`, you can't easily tell which of them is used to define `size_t`. Whether that's a problem friends on  what the OP is doing (which is a bit clearer with the latest comment).